# Excel VBA isn't Validating integer values correctly for comparison

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I am trying to go through cells that have a value of less than 50 in a column(R:R)

Here is the code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Sheets("Pyxis Inventory 6North1 and 6No").Select
    Cells(1).EntireRow.Copy (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").EntireRow)
    Cells(1).EntireRow.Copy (Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").EntireRow)

    Dim val1, val2 As String
    Dim i, j, x As Integer
    Dim colCount As Integer
    Dim daysUnused As Boolean
    Dim daysVal As Integer
    colCount = Sheets("Pyxis Inventory 6North1 and 6No").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    daysUnused = IsEmpty(Sheets("Settings").Range("B2"))
    If daysUnused = True Then
        'do nothing yet

    ElseIf daysUnused = False Then
        daysVal = Sheets("Settings").Range("B2").Value
        For x = 2 To colCount
            If Cells(x, 18).Value <= daysVal Then
                Cells(x, 18).EntireRow.Copy (Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Offset(x, 0))
                Cells(x, 18).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
         Next x
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is that it doesn't delete rows with numbers less than 50.

I have formatted the cells in the column 18 to be of number only as well.

What i want to do is basically sort, but instead of keeping the values I want to delete anything that is less than 50 or whatever the user enters for daysVal variable.

Thank you

Comment: To start with it, it is best practise when deleting rows to start at the bottom and work up. e.g. `For x = colCount to 2 step -1`.

Comment: This is probably the answer right there. If row 3 gets deleted, row 4 moves up, the next iteration checks what used to be row 5. It's essentially skipping rows.

Comment: On a side note on your code, don't use Integer in VBA, use Long instead and this: Dim i, j, x As Integer doesn't do what you think it does, it should be: Dim i As Long, j As Long, x As Long You have to name the type for every variable even on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with it, it is best practise when deleting rows to start at the bottom and work up. e.g. `For x = colCount to 2 step -1`.

The `If daysUnused = True` and `ElseIf daysUnused = False Then` are over-evaluating a simple boolean. The latter could be shortened to `Else`. By strict definition, if you are not going to do anything when True, a `Not` should be more than enough.

```
daysUnused = IsEmpty(Sheets("Settings").Range("B2"))
If Not daysUnused Then
    daysVal = Sheets("Settings").Range("B2").Value
    For x = colCount to 2 step -1
        If Cells(x, 18).Value <= daysVal Then
            Cells(x, 18).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Offset(x, 0)
            Cells(x, 18).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
     Next x
End If
```

It sounds like you fell into the row-skipping trap that makes bottom-to-top (and right-to-left when deleting columns) a canonical practise. Hopefully the above will help you tighten up your code.

Comment: awesome, what does the step -1 mean?? I am fairly new to VBA this is my first program haha I am used to C and Java, but it seems that the language is very weird when compared to the latter.

Comment: @user3866172 - If you start at the bottom and work up, you are going to want to go through row *9, 8, 7, 6...* not *2, 3, 4, ...*. The *Step* is the amount added to *x* in each iteration of the loop. If you are unclear on programming syntax, MSDN is a good place to look. [For...Next Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)